# Rails 5 Strong Params for array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form:

```
.row
  .col-lg-6
    = form_tag my_quizzes_path do
      - @questions.each do |question|
        = fields_for @my_quiz do |p|
          .field
            %p= question.title
            = p.label :answer
            = radio_button_tag "my_quiz[#{question.id}][answer]", '0'
            = radio_button_tag "my_quiz[#{question.id}][answer]", '1'
            = hidden_field_tag "my_quiz[#{question.id}][question_id]", question.id
            = hidden_field_tag "my_quiz[#{question.id}][user_id]", current_user.id

      .actions
      = submit_tag
```

generates this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"gJYhNisJDuLkfgm3rmy5VBJZ2koMVH0SUJPK+3Z3avZ2cju6GTmS2etr62dx+xFoWrKnrsrKt/lZg9F2o5sIsA==",
 "my_quiz"=>
  {"4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7"=>{"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "32722fb7-3ad4-4614-9e8b-0ea6ee5e3838"=>{"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"32722fb7-3ad4-4614-9e8b-0ea6ee5e3838", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "e38b673d-789a-4025-859c-f8a6e6dd80b0"=>{"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"e38b673d-789a-4025-859c-f8a6e6dd80b0", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "267f7fab-3a8a-4e3e-8642-a1035c7aa850"=>{"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"267f7fab-3a8a-4e3e-8642-a1035c7aa850", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "fd320da5-44d8-4328-a1b1-0ccc2115b49d"=>{"answer"=>"0", "question_id"=>"fd320da5-44d8-4328-a1b1-0ccc2115b49d", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "eab94286-cfeb-40ae-be5f-3d54538d6b0c"=>{"answer"=>"0", "question_id"=>"eab94286-cfeb-40ae-be5f-3d54538d6b0c", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "8b85ff1e-ccdc-4ca5-b289-19505551e305"=>{"answer"=>"0", "question_id"=>"8b85ff1e-ccdc-4ca5-b289-19505551e305", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "b00aa7a6-1072-4fcd-9faa-fcca16046dcb"=>{"answer"=>"0", "question_id"=>"b00aa7a6-1072-4fcd-9faa-fcca16046dcb", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "fc329254-4dba-4a61-ac71-3e148bb8a7fc"=>{"answer"=>"0", "question_id"=>"fc329254-4dba-4a61-ac71-3e148bb8a7fc", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
   "60791317-ae09-4d28-9569-8b95f7bd8c87"=>{"answer"=>"0", "question_id"=>"60791317-ae09-4d28-9569-8b95f7bd8c87", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"}},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

And this is my create and white list methods

```
def create
  params["my_quiz"].each do |question_id, data|
    @my_quiz = MyQuiz.new(my_quiz_params)
    @my_quiz.save
  end

  redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "Thank you taking the quiz!"
end

...

def my_quiz_params
  params.require(:my_quiz).permit(my_quiz: [:question_id, :user_id, :answer])
end
```

When I hist `Save` I get the unpermitted params for the ids

```
 Unpermitted parameters: 
 :4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7, 
 :32722fb7-3ad4-4614-9e8b-0ea6ee5e3838, 
 :e38b673d-789a-4025-859c-f8a6e6dd80b0, 
 :267f7fab-3a8a-4e3e-8642-a1035c7aa850, 
 :fd320da5-44d8-4328-a1b1-0ccc2115b49d, 
 :eab94286-cfeb-40ae-be5f-3d54538d6b0c, 
 :8b85ff1e-ccdc-4ca5-b289-19505551e305, 
 :b00aa7a6-1072-4fcd-9faa-fcca16046dcb, 
 :fc329254-4dba-4a61-ac71-3e148bb8a7fc, 
 :60791317-ae09-4d28-9569-8b95f7bd8c87
```

I feel like the problem is with the hash itself. I can go for something like the create method below but that does not feel like the Rails way.

```
def create
  return params[:my_quiz].each do |k, v|
    puts "Values of V"
    puts v.permit(:question_id, :user_id, :answer).inspect
    q = MyQuiz.new(v.permit(:question_id, :user_id, :answer))
    q.save!
    q
  end
  redirect #somewhere
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to whitelist manually all those parameters, something like this:

```
def my_quiz_params
  params.require(:my_quiz).permit(
    "4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7": [:question_id, :user_id, :answer],
    "32722fb7-3ad4-4614-9e8b-0ea6ee5e3838": [:question_id, :user_id, :answer]
    #...
  )
end
```

Notice that, since you already added `:my_quiz` in `require`, you don't need to add it also to `permit`.

But i guess you don't want that, so you could use `permit!` instead:

```
def my_quiz_params
  params.require(:my_quiz).permit!
end
```

Be aware that `permit!` will allow **any** parameter to come through `my_quiz` group.

---

An alternative (if your desired behavior permits) will be to remove `question.id` from your form:

```
.row
  .col-lg-6
    = form_tag my_quizzes_path do
      - @questions.each do |question|
        = fields_for @my_quiz do |p|
          .field
            %p= question.title
            = p.label :answer
            = radio_button_tag "my_quiz[][answer]", '0'
            = radio_button_tag "my_quiz[][answer]", '1'
            = hidden_field_tag "my_quiz[][question_id]", question.id
            = hidden_field_tag "my_quiz[][user_id]", current_user.id

      .actions
      = submit_tag
```

So you will receive your parameters without that id (you are already sending it in `:question_id`):

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"gJYhNisJDuLkfgm3rmy5VBJZ2koMVH0SUJPK+3Z3avZ2cju6GTmS2etr62dx+xFoWrKnrsrKt/lZg9F2o5sIsA==",
  "my_quiz"=>[
    {"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
    {"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"32722fb7-3ad4-4614-9e8b-0ea6ee5e3838", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
    {"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"e38b673d-789a-4025-859c-f8a6e6dd80b0", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},
    ...
    ]
  "commit"=>"Submit"
}
```

And your whitelist method would change to:

```
def my_quiz_params
  params.require(:my_quiz).permit([:question_id, :user_id, :answer])
end
```

Comment: If I remove the ID the radio boxes in the form will not work properly because all of them will have the same name.

I was trying to get the params to look something like
`"question" => "4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7"=>{"answer"=>"1", "question_id"=>"4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7", "user_id"=>"397b17a9-005d-4b65-ba81-668582acb12b"},`

so my whitelist would be `params.require(:my_quiz).permit(:question => [:question_id, :user_id, :answer])`

Comment: @Marrento The way you propose can't be done, you can only assign one `key => value`, you can't do `key => value => value`.  Maybe this is a good time to use `permit!`, otherwise you may go with some javascript/jquery to manipulate DOM before sending your form.

Comment: thanks. I was hitting the thing to many time before realizing what was happening. I have the solution at the end of my initial post I just need to make it pretty :)

Comment: @Marrento Great! In fact that way you get the exact same result you will get with `params.require(:my_quiz).permit!`. Good luck!

Comment: This was an interesting little challenge. My thought was to follow the paradigm of nested attributes with 2 models. The diference is that nested attributes expects an array. So it will save the Parent Object and loop through the children. Here in the this case. The idea is not much like nested attributes but more like dynamic generated form. I don't even thinkk I need to use fields_for. Anyways I'll clean up my form and use params.require(:my_quiz).permit!

Comment: using params.require(:my_quiz).permit! returns an error message `unknown attribute '4e9a4356-2c18-4310-9502-6f287a3d47d7' for MyQuiz.`

Comment: @Marrento That's odd it should work (i tested successfully). Can you share your console/log output?